# How to push a line of text down in a textarea box?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's just say I have this function(`function()` not shown):

```
document.getElementById("chatDisplay").value= document.getElementById("chatDisplay").value + userName + ":" + document.getElementById("textBox").value
```

what I want to do is between `chatDisplay`(within) the `.value=` and the `userName`is too push that line of code down(similar to a `<br>`).Is there anyway to get that done?

Comment: Probably with CSS `margin` or `padding`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\n`. It works exactly as `<br>` but it is used for text. It means *new line*

```
...."chatDisplay").value + "\n" + userName....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `&#10;` Line Feed and `&#13;` Carriage Return instead of `<br/>`:

```html
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>Hello.&#13;&#10;World&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;How are you?</textarea>
```